# How to mount a docker image as a volume via docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a build process that produces static html files. At the end of the build I copy the built files into a new docker image:

```
FROM scratch
COPY --from=build /src/build/web /app
```

Now I have an nginx service that needs to get access to those files under /app from the image above to serve the statically. Is it possible to mount my data only image directly as a volume?

Comment: Why is a volume important here?  Instead of trying to build an empty (non-runnable) image containing only the static assets, could you start the final stage `FROM nginx` and copy the files there, running without a volume?

Comment: @DavidMaze That's what I ended up doing. At the time of writing I was not aware that the CMD/ENTRYPOINT is getting inherited, so I was worried that this could possibly lead to fails later when manually copying it.